# Grouping css classes into one

Tags: css

Is it possible to group a bunch of classes into one for example:

```
 <button id="buttonCalculate" class="ui-btn ui-mini my-btn">Calculate</button>
```

It would be nice to group "ui-btn ui-mini my-btn" into a single class

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of it?

Comment: So that when you have to add or delete a class, you just do it in one place instead of search and replace.

Comment: You mean, with javascriptp or jQuery?

Comment: I guess they mean in their stylesheet as it's tagged with `css`. Please explain more?

Comment: Maybe this feature is not supported by css.  But I still think it is a  convenient thing to have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can using CSS Mixins

Try reading this
http://wynnnetherland.com/journal/css-mixins-vs-multiple-classes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can group multiple classes in a single statement!

Like the one you're having!

```
<button id="buttonCalculate" class="ui-btn ui-mini my-btn">Calculate</button>
```

This is OK! And all the classes would be applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain css if you want to apply properties to this element when all three classes are present.

```
.ui-btn.ui-mini.my-btn { }
```